# Why did a colored emoji on a button text turn black and white?

Tags: html, css

Please check this URL: https://iedcpg.org.br/doe/

I have this button, which some days ago the hearts were red:

[image]

If you select the button text content...

[image]

... and paste it on the Chrome address bar, the hearts are still red ...

[image]

But now the hearts are on the text color (white).

What's wrong? How to have those hearts back in red?

Comment: Because of `color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #1e73be;
    background-color: #1e73be;;` in your CSS

Comment: Apply `color:red` to same element and it will be red. These emoji follows text color rules

Comment: @CherryDT Ok, but as I said, some days ago the hearts were red

Comment: @mplungjan have you tested? Because disabling them doesn't change anything...

Comment: @CherryDT You are right, thanks! Please, put your suggestion as an answer for me to close this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to the font and text rendering engine how the emoji is displayed. It will look different on different devices, and, as you discovered, can even look different on different places on the same device. You also wouldn't complain that your `a` looks like `ɑ`, it's a similar thing here.

I assume Chrome changed it because it was unexpected to be rendered as emoji.

However, there are solutions for your problem:

1. Style the text yourself or use a glyph font or SVG icon, then you have full control over how it looks.
2. Append the VS16 character (`&#FE0F;`) to select Emoji rendering for the previous character*. This way, `❤` (`&#2764;`) turns into `❤️` (`&#2764;&#FE0F;`).

<sub>*: That is a [variation selector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)). There is also VS15 (`&#FE0E;`) which does the opposite: forcing characters normally displayed as emojis into text rendering.</sub>

Comment: In this case, I believe the emoji color rendering issue described here is due to a recent bug in Chrome.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @JohnK I don't think so, see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this issue can also be caused by a recent [bug in Chrome 96+](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1266022&q=emoji&can=1) that made emojis render black and white when the font weight is set to anything that requires synthetic bolding for the given font.

If this is the case, eliminating "font-weight" from the style, or adding "font-weight: normal", will show emojis in color again.  (Or just wait for the bug to be patched.)

Comment: [Doesn't seem like that's the case though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmpef.png). In fact U+2764's rendering [can vary by platform (`text-vs`)](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-style.html#text-vs_plain) and the correct way to express intent to have it always rendered as emoji is [by appending U+FE0F (`text+es`)](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-style.html#text+es_plain). Also, this is a bug with Chrome 96+ which was still in Beta at the time this question was posted, and the OP didn't mention non-release browser branches, and when I confirmed it I also used regular Chrome.

Comment: If you go to the page the OP linked, use devtools to put the non-emoji-selected hearts back and manually set `font-weight: normal;` it [doesn't work either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYit0.jpg).

Comment: While emoji rendering does vary by platform, that the issue came up right when 96+ entered beta, and follows the exact symptoms (used to work) points to the likely use of a beta version. Also, setting "font-weight: normal;" for the given element [does work for me](https://i.ibb.co/ThPtjbK/Untitled.jpg) in 96+.

Comment: What you are referring to is that the hearts are now broken _again_ for the reason you mentioned (but broken _differently_ - they are now an _outline_, not a _full_ heart, and in the devtools they do show red and not black - unlike shown in the OP's screenshots). This is a different problem with a different solution though. When you now put `font-weight: regular`, it works **because the OP already applied my solution on that page**. Remove my solution (replace the `❤️` by `❤` again) and it will be white _even with your fix_.

Comment: If you want to share this solution, modify your answer so it explains that this is a different solution for a different problem (not "this case") and needs to be applied on top of the existing solution (since it's worth to share here anyway so that people can find it by googling, given that the problems _are_ similar enough), or maybe even create a new question that actually addresses this **new, different** problem and self-answer it

Comment: (Sorry I meant `font-weight: normal`, not `font-weight: regular`, of course.) - Bottom line: Chrome 95 changed the default representation of the heart (without VS16) to text, and Chrome 96 broke Emojis in some bold text. Two different things. (And U+2764 without U+FE0F is still text in Chrome 96, even with `font-size normal`.)